# Websocket not working in SSL

Tags: javascript, xml, tomcat, ssl

I am working on a chat program in which I need to use https. I have set up https,  but now the websocket isn't working.
In `server.xml` I have made these changes for https :

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
        port="8443" keystoreFile="/Users/rameshj/.keystore" keystorePass="public"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
        secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

In HTML I use websocket like :

```
var ch = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/Chat/chat");
```

I get an error saying :

```
WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: d
```

What should I do now?

Comment: That bit of XML looks like Tomcat. If so, maybe you should add a Tomcat tag to your question.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I will add it